# Session resetting PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm using session variables in my php application, and I put `session_start()` at the first line (after the php, of course) of all my pages. But I'm losing data from two pages before.

Example: If I store `$_SESSION['var1']`, in the next page I will retrieve its value correctly, but if I go one more page ahead, I lose the data.

I use `session_start()` in all pages and I only reset the session at the index page where my user login-in.

Did someone pass through this and know what can I do? I'm testing using wamp, and in the localhost the problem doesn't happen. It only happens at my company's godaddy server (with cpanel hosting).

Comment: post your full code for all pages. This is guesswork. Use error reporting when in doubt and `var_dump()`.

Comment: If not, then you've been given an answer; see that. It's out of my hands.

Comment: Are the scripts running under the same domain/subdomain?

Comment: I checked phpinfo of both my servers, and the configuration for session handling is the same to both of them. I can post my code, but I don't think it'll help, the problem seems to be on the server. And yes, the scripts are running under the same subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
My index.php was destroying the session data, even if the page doesn't pass trhought it, the session was always erased.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a comment
Its the problem of the server and not the script. Usually to maintain the server load the sessions that are created at your site can expire in a short amount of time. There are ways like editing the php.ini file of the www directory but every hosting server could have different methods.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: *"I guess"* - Yes, that is correct; a guess. Edit: this comment as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43459163/1

Comment: *"Its the problem of the server and not the script"* - That has already been established; now what's the solution to this? As @JayBlanchard said; this is  a comment and IMHO doesn't solve the question.